# MongoDB : aggregate $project take array current item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hi I have mongodb query like this .

```
.aggregate(
            [
                { $match : { comment_box : "somdata" } },

                { $project : {
                    comment : 1,                      
                        created_at: 1,
                        current_date: "$replies.created_at",
                    },
                    dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$created_at"] }
                }},
            ]
        )
```

Imagine that I want to get created_at value from replies array in current date field. but this query returns

```
current_date: [
   "2016-03-08T13:48:27.882Z",
   "2016-03-08T14:26:22.194Z"
]
```

instead of current created_at value of each element from this array

I have tried many ways but got errors

```
current_date: "$replies.0.created_at",
current_date: "$replies.$.created_at",
current_date: "$$replies.created_at",
```

and etc

please help me to retrieve data like this

```
current_date:"2016-03-08T13:48:27.882Z",
```

Comment: How do you determine the current date from an array of dates, is it always the first element in the array or you need to order the array descending then get the first item?

Comment: Can you show sample documents?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/CrEXp this is result

Comment: https://codeshare.io/bbKVy and this is my mongoose schema

Comment: Update your post instead of pasting external Url.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you want the latest comment date. In that case, you can just take the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/):

```
current_date: { $max: '$replies.created_at' }
```

Demo:

```
> db.comments.insert({_id: 0, replies: [{created_at: new Date('2017-04-03')}, {created_at: new Date('2017-02-03')} ]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.comments.insert({_id: 1, replies: []})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.comments.aggregate([{$project: {current_date: {$max: '$replies.created_at'}}}])
{ "_id" : 0, "current_date" : ISODate("2017-04-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 1, "current_date" : null }
```

Notice how the document with an empty `replies` array gets `null`.